# View Last Frame Outline While On Current

Tags: modeling, animation

Is there a way in blender to view the last frame as an outline while on the current in adobe flash it's called onion skin this is useful so we can animate better and know where the last frame was instead of going back and fourth

Answer (score 4):

When animating an armature you can use the ghost feature in the armature tab. The range value determines how many frames it will show at once.

[image]

And the result:

[image]

Update:

New result with your .blend:

[image]

[image]

Comment: didn't work i'm trying to view 7 while still on 8 as you can here https://gyazo.com/a0e65d015897d4defc0618d3187a9d21

Comment: Looks like the range value is set to zero. Try setting it to something higher.  I'll update the screenshot to make this more clear. Also try playing back the animation from the start.  Sometimes the ghosting doesn't appear the first time you turn it on.

Comment: still not working also the maximum amount is only 30 my animation has 34 frames why is it only 30 the range i'm talking about

Comment: Its 30 frames relative to the current frame.  If you're at frame 50 in your animation it'll show you frames 20 through 80.  It shows 30 frames on the front and back of the current frame which would be a total of 61 frames.

Comment: If its still not working feel free to upload your .blend here: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344/where-to-upload-blend-files-non-expiring-links

Comment: its private sorry just explain why it isn't working after following your steps i set it to 30 and set steps to 2 but nothing showing up why?

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to reproduce the problem. The ghost effect shows up for me without fail.  I'm not sure I can be much help without a .blend file.

Comment: Alright, it seems the ghost effects are showing up, its just that they aren't very obvious with your custom bones.  I found the best settings for your animation was to set the Step Size to 1, and the range to 23.  Also, you could consider changing your theme to Ubuntu Ambiance, it makes the ghost effects show up in bright purple.

Comment: did that and i don't see anything show me a screenshot also i'm trying to get this http://puu.sh/wDzAU/93a22079d1.jpg to be shown on this http://puu.sh/wDzB3/e276d01b83.png

Comment: It won't show the meshes, only the bones.  I've uploaded a gif to the answer.  There isn't a way to display ghosts of mesh objects afaik.